# How to delete all files inside public_ftp folder—and its sub folders—which are older than X days using cron job?

Tags: linux, ftp, find, cron

I want a way to run daily cron job on aserver that will delete all files only (not folders) which are older than X days from today's date, in the `public_ftp` folder and all its sub folders to a specified max depth level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /path/to/folder/toclean -mtime +5 -type f -maxdepth 3 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

This assumes that the directory you wish to clean up is /path/to/folder/toclean, just replace it with your name. The command *find -mtime +5 -type f* finds all the files (-type f) which were last modified more than (+) 5 days ago, while *-maxdepth 3* limits the depth of directory to search. The exec performs the actual removal.